# Jenkins - environment variable not setting up from pipeline

Tags: shell, shell-scripting, jenkins, pipelining

Here is my script. Im trying to set up variables in pipline shell script:

```
node {


  anyconnect = docker.image('anyconnect:1').run("--cap-add NET_ADMIN --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun -e VPN_USER=${env.USER} -e VPN_PASS=${env.PASS} --name anyconnect")

  sh 'echo "Startig anyconnect and setting route"'

  sh """
    IPADDRESS = \$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" anyconnect)
    echo $IPADDRESS
    ip route replace xx.xx.xx.xx. via $IPADDRESS
    """



  anyconnect.stop()



}
```

But im getting:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: IPADDRESS for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding

I was trying to export it and other things like useing ${env.VARIABLE} or just ${VARIABLE} still not helping to set up variable in pipeline. How it should be done with Jenkins pipelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your double quotes with single quotes to prevent `$IPADDRESS` from being interpreted as a Groovy variable:

```
  sh '''
    IPADDRESS = \$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" anyconnect)
    echo $IPADDRESS
    ip route replace xx.xx.xx.xx. via $IPADDRESS
    '''
```

Alternatively, escape the dollar sign:

```
  sh """
    IPADDRESS = \$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" anyconnect)
    echo ${'$'}IPADDRESS
    ip route replace xx.xx.xx.xx. via ${'$'}IPADDRESS
    """
```